# Handle Api response in Ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

hey I am trying to learn ktor for my api request. I am reading [Response validation](https://ktor.io/docs/response-validation.html) in doc.

**ApiResponse.kt**

```
sealed class ApiResponse<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(
        val data: T?
    ) : ApiResponse<T>()

    data class Error(
        val exception: Throwable? = null,
        val responseCode: Int = -1
    ) : ApiResponse<Nothing>()

    fun handleResult(onSuccess: ((responseData: T?) -> Unit)?, onError: ((error: Error) -> Unit)?) {
        when (this) {
            is Success -> {
                onSuccess?.invoke(this.data)
            }
            is Error -> {
                onError?.invoke(this)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class ErrorResponse(
    var errorCode: Int = 1,
    val errorMessage: String = "Something went wrong"
)
```

I have this **ApiResponse** class in which, I want to handle api response through this [post](https://medium.com/codex/kotlin-sealed-classes-for-better-handling-of-api-response-6aa1fbd23c76). As you see in the link, there is function called `fetchResult`, inside that code is checking every time `response.code()` and route according to domain specific **Success** or **Error** body. Is there any better way it will automatically route on specific domain rather than checking every time in ktor.

```
actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit) = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    config(this)
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.SIMPLE
        level = LogLevel.BODY
    }
    expectSuccess = false
    HttpResponseValidator {
        handleResponseExceptionWithRequest { exception, _ ->
            val errorResponse: ErrorResponse
            when (exception) {
                is ResponseException -> {
                    errorResponse = exception.response.body()
                    errorResponse.errorCode = exception.response.status.value
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**KtorApi.kt**

```
class KtorApi(private val httpClient: HttpClient) {
    suspend fun getAbc(): Flow<KtorResponse> {
        return httpClient.get {
            url("abc")
        }.body()
    }
}
```

Comment: Documentation contains examples, including check for response code. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PylypDukhov thanks for reply. I added my code. Can you please guide me.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your question. If it's "is it required to throw exceptions from `validateResponse` to get request", then no - you have access to request in `validateResponse`, it's part of response `validateResponse { response -> response.request }`. Otherwise, what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @PylypDukhov I update my question to help to you clearly understand, what I want to learn or achieve. I trying to learn callback feature, but not able to understand. How to route in callback. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push through the `HttpResponsePipeline` an object of the `ApiResponse` type by intercepting the pipeline in the `Transform` phase. In the interceptor, you can use a `ContentConverter` to deserialize a response body to an object of generic type (`out T : Any`). Please note that this solution doesn't allow you to catch network exceptions. If you want to handle network or other exceptions you have to write a function that will return an object of the `ApiResponse` type as described in the article. Here is a complete example:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.serialization.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.*
import io.ktor.util.reflect.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val client = HttpClient(Apache)

    val converter = KotlinxSerializationConverter(Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
    client.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) { (info, body) ->
        if (body !is ByteReadChannel) return@intercept

        val response = context.response
        val apiResponse = if (response.status.value in 200..299) {
            ApiResponse.Success(
                converter.deserialize(context.request.headers.suitableCharset(), info.ofInnerClassParameter(0), body)
            )
        } else {
            ApiResponse.Error(responseCode = response.status.value)
        }

        proceedWith(HttpResponseContainer(info, apiResponse))
    }

    val r: ApiResponse<HttpBin> = client.get("https://httpbin.org/get").body()
    r.handleResult({ data ->
        println(data?.origin)
    }) { error ->
        println(error.responseCode)
    }
}

fun TypeInfo.ofInnerClassParameter(index: Int): TypeInfo {
    // Error handling is needed here
    val kTypeProjection = kotlinType!!.arguments[index]
    val kType = kTypeProjection.type!!
    return TypeInfo(kType.classifier as KClass<*>, kType.platformType, kType)
}

@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class HttpBin(val origin: String)

sealed class ApiResponse<out T : Any> {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(
        val data: T?
    ) : ApiResponse<T>()

    data class Error(
        val exception: Throwable? = null,
        val responseCode: Int = -1
    ) : ApiResponse<Nothing>()

    fun handleResult(onSuccess: ((responseData: T?) -> Unit)?, onError: ((error: Error) -> Unit)?) {
        when (this) {
            is Success -> {
                onSuccess?.invoke(this.data)
            }
            is Error -> {
                onError?.invoke(this)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with nested types, e.g. ApiResponse<PageData<User>>. How can I handle type nesting? It currenlty says `Serializer for class 'PageData' is not found` for such a scenario.

Comment: Update: Edited answer to handle that too.