# Unresolved reference: responsePipeline in ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am working in ktor. I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72018984/18958467). I want to use **responsePipeline** on my **androidMain**. But I am getting error `Unresolved reference: responsePipeline`. Actually I created my **HttpClient** with **OkHttp** in my **androidMain**. I don't know why I cannot use in my file. Can someone please guide me.

**androidMain**

```
actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit) = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) {
    }
    config(this)
    install(Logging) {
        logger = Logger.SIMPLE
        level = LogLevel.BODY
    }
}
```

**commonMain**

```
expect fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit = {}): HttpClient
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responsePipeline` is a property of `HttpClient` class, and you are trying to access it on an instance of `HttpClientConfig`.

Lamda of `HttpClient(OkHttp)` returns an object of type `HttpClientConfig` which doesn't have a property named `reponsePipeline`.

To use `responsePipeline` you have to create an instance of `HttpClient`, and after that you can use it.

You can create a method which returns your configured `httpClient`

```
fun createHttpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit): HttpClient {
    val httpClient = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        config(this)
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.SIMPLE
            level = LogLevel.BODY
        }
    }
    httpClient.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) {

    }
    return httpClient
}
```

Assign this to the actual definition.

```
actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit) = createHttpClient(config)
```